# SQL Script to Drop old AD logins, Inactive SQL Logins and all related Users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, users, logins

Related Question: [SQL Server script to delete accounts no longer in Active Directory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31478/sql-server-script-to-delete-accounts-no-longer-in-active-directory/)

Whilst the above question points out the rather handy `sp_validatelogins` procedure, i'd like to extend this procedure to then drop the logins, search all databases & drop any related users.

Id also like to drop all SQL logins that have not been logged in for over X months - and again, drop any related users across all databases.

Before I go writing all this from scratch - I cant help but feel I'd be re-inventing the wheel - someone must surly have written a script to do this already but i'm not having much luck finding one!

If no one has a script up their sleeve to do all this, scripts to do parts of them would be just as good - I've no problem merging them into a single script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full script for the task. But maybe this script could be a start.

It returns a list of logins that don't have permissions granted. Using `sp_msforeachdb` it searches on all databases using `sys.database_principals` and `sys.database_role_members`. You could insert the result in a temp table and then do whatever you need to do with that list.

I'm sure I found this script some time ago somewhere and made some small modifications to fit my needs. But can't find where I found the original one. So sorry if no link provided to the author(s).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #all_users (db       VARCHAR(70),
                        SID      VARBINARY(85),
                        stat     VARCHAR(50))
EXEC MASTER.sys.sp_msforeachdb
     'INSERT INTO #all_users  
         SELECT ''?'', CONVERT(varbinary(85), sid) , 
          CASE WHEN  r.role_principal_id IS NULL AND p.major_id IS NULL 
          THEN ''no_db_permissions''  ELSE ''db_user'' END
         FROM [?].sys.database_principals u LEFT JOIN [?].sys.database_permissions p 
           ON u.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id  
           AND p.permission_name <> ''CONNECT''
          LEFT JOIN [?].sys.database_role_members r 
           ON u.principal_id = r.member_principal_id
          WHERE u.SID IS NOT NULL AND u.type_desc <> ''DATABASE_ROLE'''

IF EXISTS 
   (SELECT l.name
       FROM   sys.server_principals l
              LEFT JOIN sys.server_permissions p
                   ON  l.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id
                   AND p.permission_name <> 'CONNECT SQL'
              LEFT JOIN sys.server_role_members r
                   ON  l.principal_id = r.member_principal_id
              LEFT JOIN #all_users u
                   ON  l.sid = u.sid
       WHERE  r.role_principal_id IS NULL
              AND l.type_desc <> 'SERVER_ROLE'
              AND p.major_id IS NULL
   )
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT l.name     LoginName,
           l.type_desc,
           l.is_disabled,
           ISNULL(u.stat + ', but is user in ' + u.db + ' DB', 'no_db_users') 
           db_perms,
           CASE 
                WHEN p.major_id IS NULL AND r.role_principal_id IS NULL THEN 
                     'no_srv_permissions'
                ELSE 'na'
           END                 srv_perms
    FROM   sys.server_principals l
           LEFT JOIN sys.server_permissions p
                ON  l.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id
                AND p.permission_name <> 'CONNECT SQL'
           LEFT JOIN sys.server_role_members r
                ON  l.principal_id = r.member_principal_id
           LEFT JOIN #all_users u
                ON  l.sid = u.sid
    WHERE  l.type_desc <> 'SERVER_ROLE'
           AND ((u.db IS NULL
                       AND p.major_id IS NULL
                       AND r.role_principal_id IS NULL
                 )
                   OR (u.stat = 'no_db_permissions'
                          AND p.major_id IS NULL
                          AND r.role_principal_id IS NULL
                      ))
    ORDER BY 1, 4
END
DROP TABLE #all_users
```

Sample result:

```
LoginName            type_desc  is_disabled         db_perms                                        srv_perms
app_agentjobreader   SQL_LOGIN      0       no_db_permissions, but is user in mydb DB           no_srv_permissions
app_web_general      SQL_LOGIN      0       no_db_permissions, but is user in mydb_second DB    no_srv_permissions
app_web_maker        SQL_LOGIN      0       no_db_permissions, but is user in mydb_third DB     no_srv_permissions
```

Comment: stop using the undocumented ms_foreachDB. There is [A more reliable and more flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb)